# Where should I ask about blogging on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like start a blog about a general topic, for example: programming, learning languages (English, Spanish, Korean, Japanese, Chinese, French, Italian, etc.), history, engineering, math, opinion personal, and other topics that I like. I am learning about it, but I always watched blogs about only one topic and not multiple topics on the Internet. Where could I ask about how make a blog like this on the Internet?

I saw only two places in:

**Academia** and **Writing** on Stack Exchange. Where could I ask about it here?

Please help me to find an excellent place for asking here.

**EDIT - UPDATE**

Okay, I want to make a blog personal where I could share something that I know. For example, I am developer and I would share my code and my tips, etc. and I love math and I would like share article about math,etc and I like  another topic like history, languages, etc., and then I would like find a place where I could ask about "How can I start a personal blog  like this?"

Comment: @AnneDaunted as you can see I edit that question and I think explain more okay I said Academia because this site about education and my vision with this blogs is the education but maybe this site is more for teacher I think and writing because I will going to write post but maybe there  place is for people that make book

Comment: What aspect of blogging? *[Writers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour)* has [the tag "blog"](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog), with 85 questions.

Comment: (Sorry, [it used to be called *"Writers"*; now it is *"Writing"*](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1545/can-the-name-of-our-site-in-sede-be-updated).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have questions about the **technical aspects** of creating a blog, look for a relevant technical site, like [Wordpress.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [Web Applications.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

If you have questions about **how to present** your content, for example structuring text + example code for readability, you can ask on [Writing.SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

If you have questions about deciding what to write, those aren't on-topic anywhere on the network.  That's the part that *you*, first and foremost, have to bring to blogging.  You might get some brainstorming help in the chat rooms for sites about your topic area (like [software engineering](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), [history](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=history.stackexchange.com), the language sites, etc).

Comment: Writing ? mm I think this site is for people that make book or not?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH you help me a lot with it

Comment: @simon Writing is for all kinds of writing.  Blog posts are writing.  So we can handle your *writing*-related questions, but not questions about blogging platforms and SEO and stuff like that.

Comment: oh thank you I will goning to check out the site